# How to mimic pgsql row_to_array()

Tags: mysql

I wish to get a JSON_OBJECT of a table.
While pgsql has row_to_Json, MySQL does not, and I wish to mimic this.
Of course, I could do this..

```
    SELECT JSON_ARRAYAGG(JSON_OBJECT(id, name)) FROM my_table;
```

However, if I do not know the names of the fields, and I wish to do something like this:

```
SELECT JSON_ARRAYAGG(JSON_OBJECT(*)) FROM my_table;
```

Of course, this does not work. So I tried:

```
SET @fields = (select group_concat(my_table.res) FROM (SELECT COLUMN_NAME AS res FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS WHERE TABLE_NAME='my_table') AS my_table);
SELECT JSON_OBJECT(@fields) FROM my_table;
```

Which does not work also, because a single string is passed to JSON_OBJECT.

How to get the JSON representation of a row from any table?

Comment: You'll need to use a stored procedure that queries INFORMATION_SCHEMA to create dynamic SQL and execute it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to use a stored procedure to execute dynamic SQL. The procedure should contain code like this:

```
SET @fields = (
    select group_concat('"', column_name, '", `', column_name, '`') 
    FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS 
    WHERE TABLE_NAME=table_name_param
);
SET @sql = CONCAT('SELECT JSON_OBJECT(', @fields, ') FROM `', table_name_param, '`';
PREPARE stmt FROM @sql;
EXECUTE stmt;
DEALLOCATE PREPARE stmt;
```

Comment: Thanks Barar, this has helped me, however I get an error "SQL Error 1241: Operand should contain 1 column(s).

Comment: I'm not sure if it's the reason, but I just realized that I'm not giving the correct arguments to `JSON_OBJECT`. It needs to be alternating keys and values. I've added the column names as the keys, see if that fixes it.

Comment: Yes, adding the column names works, however, that will not make it a re-usable function, to list a row from ANY table, which may have different columns.
I am not even sure if this can be done...

Comment: You can make the table name a parameter of the procedure. I've updated the answer to show that.